# Fragments Click Events Problems in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on fragment concepts in andorid.I am adding multiple layouts into one FrameLayout,

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.addToBackStack("web");
ft.setTransitionStyle(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_ENTER_MASK);
Fragment fragment = new TestFragment();
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.right_to_left_remove, R.anim.right_to_left_add);
ft.add(R.id.test, fragment);
ft.commit();
```

I clicked the button in fragment1, fragment2 added above with fragment1, when click the same area of fragement2 layouts with no buttons another one fragment added. Fragment1 button clickable in Fragment2, so the fragments multiple time adding.

How do I disable click events in fragment2 layouts??

Thanks,

Comment: Is it possible add multiple fragments into single framelayout using add method??

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ft.replace` instead of `ft.add`

If you want to use `ft.add`, at lest remove the old fragment:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.main, new Fragment1(), "frag1");
ft.add(R.id.main, new Fragment2(), "frag2");
ft.commit();

// Later on
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
// Manually remove fragments
ft.remove(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("frag1"));
ft.remove(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("frag2"));
ft.add(R.id.main, new Fragment1(), "newFrag1");
ft.commit();
```

Comment: When i reuse the same fragment with different ids (say R.id.test,R.id.test1),have to send differents id to fragments.i don't want to send ids between fragmetns that is why i choose add method..

Comment: Take a look at my edit. I've never seen somebody using add without using the remove method.

Comment: Please give your suggestions for disable click event in fragment2 layout.why click event working multiple times? is i need to add anything into fragment manager?

Comment: I can add and remove fragments with same fragment layouts.i want to add multiple layouts without replace method?